# Group multiple windows tiled within another window

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, desktop, window-manager

A current example of my requirement is that I have 3 or 4 PowerShell windows open, and minimised to the taskbar. Is there any way, besides creating a second desktop, that I could tile, say 4, PowerShell windows inside another host window, so that when I restore that host from the taskbar, I have simultaneous access to all four PowerShell windows, tiled in the host, so that in this case each one takes up 1/4 of the host's space?

Comment: Can you just stick them on their own virtual desktop?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 has multiple desktops, but a Windows Desktop is a whole environment, so if I have Visual Studio on dt1, and my collection of windows on dt2, I lose one when I switch to the other. Unless you mean another desktop on a VM, which might kind of work. I was just hoping for something like an old MS Office app, with the multiple document interface, but across processes. Maybe more achievable of all child windows are process instances of the same app, but that is what I actually want, e.g. many copies of say a download manager, all hosted/managed by this unicorn of a tool I'm seeking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Needs a tiny bit of poking, but you can do this with conemu

[image]

I've turned off quake mode (hamburger menu, main, uncheck quake style slide down), started a new powershell window, and split it by righclicking and picking the "split to right" or "split to bottom" options.

I've used the portable mode to test, and it seems to work, though if you're happy with it, there's a full installer.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. The question is clearly not about PowerShell consoles only, and I only used PowerShell as "A current example of my requirement". But, I am very grateful anyway. You have helped a lot with the PowerShell aspect. I am glad you have got many upvotes, and am more than happy to grant you the bounty.

Comment: Oh, this should work with other shells too. Not sure how it'd play out with a mix of them, didn't think of testing it - unless you meant actual windows. That I have no clue how to do.

Comment: Yes, I actually mean windows. I suspect that would need some pretty serious and low-level Win32 coding